# Jquery Image gallery with Next/Previous buttons doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a slide gallery of images. It doesn't need to run automatically. I just want it to have a previous and next button so the user can navigate manually.

My problem is my code doesn't work. The NEXT button, it only jumps to the second image and never goes to the remaining image when I try clicking it again. The PREVIOUS button when clicked, should show the last image or the previous one but it doesn't.

Please help me out. See my code [here](http://codepen.io/ajnoguerra/pen/BpcoH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not removing the previous class before you add it to the current item.  So once you've hit next, you have 2 items that are previous and it finds the first one.

```
$('.next').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.previous').removeClass('previous');

    $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    $('.previous').hide("slide",{direction: 'left'}, 500);

    var previousId = parseInt($('.previous').attr('id'));

    $('#'+(previousId+1)).show("slide", {direction: 'right'}, 500).addClass('current');

});

$('.prev').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

            $('.previous').removeClass('previous');

    $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    $('.previous').hide("slide",{direction: 'right'}, 500);

    var previousId = parseInt($('.previous').attr('id'));
    var Id = parseInt($('.current').attr('id'));


    $('#'+(previousId-1)).show("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500).addClass('current');
```

Once you have that fixed, you'll need to take care of the case where you've hit your last image.  Do you want to stay on that image, or circle around?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the NEXT Button. Thanks to you ;) Now I'm up to this problem, I'd like to have it circle around I just don't know how could I do that. Any hints how should I start? ;(

Comment: It's just a matter of adding an if to check to see if you've gone past the end.  See this pen http://cdpn.io/FhDjA

Comment: Now that was amazing! Never thought that a simple if statement could do the magic. I'm going to study that. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I just hardcoded the number 3, if you want to make it more flexible replace that with a variable that is the count of the images in your slider. http://cdpn.io/FhDjA