# Creating a sliding image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking at some code using jQuery and JS along with HTML and CSS to create a sliding image gallery. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974616/jquery-image-gallery-with-next-previous-buttons-doesnt-work-correctly) and copied the code with the "revised" code. However, the gallery only displays the first image. The next and prev clicks do not do anything. I'm starting to learn some JS and jQuery. I've looked at this code for a while and I cannot figure out what is the issue.

Here is the script that I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider > #1').show('fade',500).addClass('current');
    $('.next').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('.previous').removeClass('previous');

        $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        $('.previous').hide("slide",{direction: 'left'}, 500);

        var previousId = parseInt($('.previous').attr('id'));

        $('#'+(previousId+1)).show("slide", {direction: 'right'}, 500).addClass('current');

    });

    $('.prev').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.previous').removeClass('previous');

        $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        $('.previous').hide("slide",{direction: 'right'}, 500);

        var previousId = parseInt($('.previous').attr('id'));
        var Id = parseInt($('.current').attr('id'));


        $('#'+(previousId-1)).show("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

I uploaded it to [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Clocker/NRJxF/).

Any help would be great! Thanks

**EDIT**
I came upon [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) and noticed that the code had two src for the scripts. I added the ui script and the jQuery works perfectly!

Comment: So... you don't need any help? Put your solution in an answer so this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The library for the slide was missing, add this for it to work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```